# What does "Multiply keyword lists to get new keyword ideas" do in the new keyword planner tool?

Tags: keyword, google-ads-api

Does any body know?
What does "Multiply keyword lists to get new keyword ideas" do in the new keyword planner tool?

Please see the attachment.[image]

Answer (score 3):

An example should hopefully make it clear: in list 1 you might enter 'cheap, cheapest, best, find' and in list 2, enter 'hotel, hotels, accommodation, hostel'.

The keyword tool will then "multiply" these lists to possible generate all combinations of the input terms, eg: 'cheap hotel, cheap hotels, cheap accommodation,...cheapest hotel, cheapest hotels,...' etc

Basically a shorthand way of typing lots of keywords.